# Loading content for bootstrap collapse with jQuery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using bootstrap collapse with jQuery ajax. Everything works well but unfortunately only once. If I try to click it again it doesn't give me the content of load_tasks anymore. It works well after I refresh the page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

   var url = base_url + '/content';

   jQuery('#collapseTwo').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {

      jQuery('#content').load(tasks_url + ' #content-section', load_content);

   });

});
```

Any ideas how I could get it work without reloading the page.

Comment: what is the value of tasks_url ? did you debug and see the issue? if possible, please show your issue in a fiddler.

Comment: tasks_url is just bootstrap collapse code which works just fine. My problem is that everything works just fine only once. The content of tasks_url is loaded nicely when I press collapse first time. Load_content is mixitup javascript code. When debuging, no errors occurs.